# Is there any method to bypass canvas security exception (external image to data string)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am figuring out how to convert external image to data string using pure javascript

Is there any method, without using a proxy server

Even if the method create a security hole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope you have to apply [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers to the server response hosting the images for this to work if it is cross domain. This does not have universal browser support either. Many Native Mobile browsers don't support it unfortunately.

Comment: That's always the problem ;)